# It is compatible to use Capacitor safe area plugin in a Cordova Ionic based app?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, capacitor, safearealayoutguide, capacitor-plugin

Considering that Cordova is now deprecated, and safe-area environment may not work in cordova-android versions above 10.0.0, **can I use the Capacitor plugin for safe-area in my Cordova application?** Are they compatible with each other?

Here's the Issue about android versions not detecting safe area: https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/1465

I was considering using this npm package for this purpose: https://www.npmjs.com/package/capacitor-plugin-safe-area

Cordova is not detecting any devices inset safe area if the Android version is above 11, but you also cannot have an Android version below 12 to publish it on the App Store. So, I am forced to migrate to Capacitor, but I was looking for some simple solution, at least for now, and then I'll migrate correctly.